# MongoDB Query a specific field in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database structure that looks something like this.

```
{
    "peopleholder": {
        "people": [
            {
                "otherdata": "asdf",
                "name": "joe"
            },
            {
                "otherdata": "asdf",
                "name": "bob"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to construct a search query to select all people who have name "bob", right?

So, I've tried some things, looking at the $all suggestion, and come up with...

```
{
    "peopleholder": {
        "people": {
            "$all": [
                {
                    "name": "bob"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried it with people just equal to `{"name": "bob"}`, as that [appears to be shorthand](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{ "peopleholder.people.name": "bob"}
```

**Source** [Mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget that this query will be case sensitive.